# React/Next.js Close one modal and open another at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, components, next.js

I'm building a server-rendered website using Node.js, Express.js, MySQL, and Next.js (framework for React). The concept is basically a Jeopardy game.

Currently what I have is I query from the database and extract all the questions. I then made a table with the $amounts and each cell in the table can be clicked on to reveal the question. When you click on a cell/question in the table, a modal opens up. It says the question and then below it there's a space to answer and a submit button.

Right now what I want to do is when I click the submit button, the current modal with the question should disappear and then a new modal featuring "feedback" basically saying correct with a checkmark or incorrect with a x symbol should pop up.

But I'm not sure how to do the above or even if that's a good way to go about this. I'm very new to this so please help me out.

Here is what I have so far. Right now when I run this code, when I click submit, the question modal disappears but the feedback modal does not pop up.

Question Modal:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import UserInput from './userInput.js';
import Feedback from "./feedback/feedback";

class SampleQ extends Component {
    static getInitialProps({query: {amount, question, answer}}) {
        return {specAmt: amount, specQ: question, specA: answer}
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showQuestion: false, // tracks visibility of first modal (the question modal in this component)
            showFeedback: false // tracks visibility of second modal (the feedback modal in other component)
        };

        this.handleShow = () => {
            this.setState({ showQuestion: true });
        };

        this.handleHide = () => {
            this.setState({ showQuestion: false });
        };

        this.submitForm = () => {
            this.setState({
                showQuestion: false, // close question modal
                showFeedback: true, // should open Feedback modal
            });
        };

        this.closeFeedback = () => {
            this.setState( { showFeedback: false }); // close Feedback modal
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Button variant="outline-danger" size = "lg" onClick={this.handleShow}>
                    $ {this.props.amount}00
                </Button>

                <Modal
                    show={this.state.showQuestion}
                    onHide={this.handleHide}
                    dialogClassName="modal-90w"
                    aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
                            Question
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <p>
                            {this.props.question}
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <UserInput
                                answer={this.props.specA}
                                handleClick={this.submitForm}
                            />
                            <Feedback
                                showModal={this.state.showFeedback}
                                onSubmit={this.closeFeedback}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default SampleQ;
```

Form for the Question Modal:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

class UserInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleClick}>
                <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formAnswer">
                    <Form.Label column sm={2}>
                        Answer
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Here"/>
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>
                <div>
                    <Button
                        variant="primary"
                        onClick={this.props.handleClick}
                    >Submit</Button>
                </div>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default UserInput;
```

Feedback Modal:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from "../../scss/modalStyle.scss";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import { AiFillCheckCircle } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

class Feedback extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                show={this.props.showModal}
                onHide={this.props.onSubmit}
                className="Feedback"
            >
            <Modal.Dialog style={[styles.modalDialog, styles.modalConfirm]}>
                <Modal.Body style={styles.modalContent}>
                    <Modal.Body style={styles.modalHeader}>
                        <Modal.Body style={styles.iconBox}>
                            <IconContext.Provider value={{ size: "70px", className: "global-class-name" }}>
                                <div>
                                    <AiFillCheckCircle />
                                </div>
                            </IconContext.Provider>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <h4 className='mx-auto'>Congratulations!</h4>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Body style={styles.modalBody}>
                        <p className="text-center">That was the correct answer.</p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Body style={styles.modalFooter}>
                        <Button
                            className="btn btn-success btn-block"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            onClick={this.props.onSubmit}
                        >
                            OK
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal.Dialog>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

export default Feedback;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the second modal the same way you handled the first one:

1. Add a key to `SampleQ` state and track the second modal's visibility with it.
2. Pass a handler changing that visibility to `true` to `UserAnswer` and invoke it on submit click.

You should not open a modal "in" another modal like this: `{modalOpen ? <Feedback showModal={this._openModal.bind(this)} closeModal={this._closeModal.bind(this)} /> : ''}`. SampleQ should store in its state the visibility of both modals.

Comment: so in SampleQ I added a key called showFeedback that tracks the visibility of the second modal. I made a handler called this.submitForm that sets the state of showFeedback to true and showQuestion to false. So this should open the second modal and close the first modal. I passed this.submitForm as a prop to UserAnswer and called it handleClick. In UserAnswer, in the Form tag, I added onSubmit={this.props.handleClick} and in the Button tag which has the submit button I added onClick={this.props.handleClick}. Now I'm just confused on where do I render the Feedback component and how do I do it?

Comment: In this situation you should put the Feedback modal next to the UserAnswer one, in the SampleQ component. They should be siblings.

Comment: I've updated the original post to reflect the code I have now. I believe I did everything you asked but for some reason, now when I click the submit button on the question modal, it just randomly clears the entire page except the navbar (essentially deleting the whole table)

Comment: You put ```Feedback``` as a child of the ```Modal.Body``` component. I advised you to put it as a sibling to the question modal. Put the ```Feedback``` component in your ```SampleQ``` component below ```</Modal>```

Comment: could you take a look at this new stackoverflow post I made? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141594/onclick-modal-makes-entire-page-disappear. I put the feedback component below Modal and it's not still working. I am now sure it is because of my configuration or installs because this sandbox has my code working: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-60141594-l4lrm. Here is all my code at github.com/ruthvikkonda/Jeopardy/tree/debug. It's something with my configuration I'm guessing but I can't figure out what