# onClick Modal makes entire page disappear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, modal-dialog, next.js

I messed around with some installs and configurations. And now for some reason my code isn't working like it used to. I'm not sure where I messed up. I've included my package.json and my next.config.js. This is how my code was working before: when I clicked on the cell in the table, it popped up the question modal. Then when I clicked submit on the question modal, the question modal would disappear and the feedback modal would pop up. Now when I click submit on the question modal, it just randomly makes the entire page disappear.

I'm on next.js 8.0.4-canary.21 and react 16.8.3. I'm not sure if the problem is with my configuration or my code.

Question Modal:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import UserInput from './userInput.js';
import Feedback from "./feedback/feedback";

class SampleQ extends Component {
    static getInitialProps({query: {amount, question, answer}}) {
        return {specAmt: amount, specQ: question, specA: answer}
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showQuestion: false, // tracks visibility of first modal (the question modal in this component)
            showFeedback: false // tracks visibility of second modal (the feedback modal in other component)
        };

        this.handleShow = () => {
            this.setState({ showQuestion: true });
        };

        this.handleHide = () => {
            this.setState({ showQuestion: false });
        };

        this.submitForm = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log(this.state.showFeedback);

            this.setState({
                showQuestion: false, // close question modal
                showFeedback: true, // should open Feedback modal
            });
        };

        this.closeFeedback = () => {
            this.setState( { showFeedback: false }); // close Feedback modal
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Button variant="outline-danger" size = "lg" onClick={this.handleShow}>
                    $ {this.props.amount}00
                </Button>

                <Modal
                    show={this.state.showQuestion}
                    onHide={this.handleHide}
                    dialogClassName="modal-90w"
                    aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
                            Question
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <p>
                            {this.props.question}
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <UserInput
                                answer={this.props.specA}
                                handleClick={this.submitForm}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
                <Feedback
                    showModal={this.state.showFeedback}
                    onSubmit={this.closeFeedback}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default SampleQ;
```

Form for the Question Modal:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

class UserInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleClick}>
                <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formAnswer">
                    <Form.Label column sm={2}>
                        Answer
                    </Form.Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Here"/>
                    </Col>
                </Form.Group>
                <div>
                    <Button
                        variant="primary"
                        onClick={this.props.handleClick}
                    >Submit</Button>
                </div>
            </Form>
        );
    }
}

export default UserInput;
```

Feedback Modal:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from "../../scss/modalStyle.scss";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import { AiFillCheckCircle } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { IconContext } from "react-icons";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

class Feedback extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                show={this.props.showModal}
                onHide={this.props.onSubmit}
                className="Feedback"
            >
            <Modal.Dialog style={[styles.modalDialog, styles.modalConfirm]}>
                <Modal.Body style={styles.modalContent}>
                    <Modal.Body style={styles.modalHeader}>
                        <Modal.Body style={styles.iconBox}>
                            <IconContext.Provider value={{ size: "70px", className: "global-class-name" }}>
                                <div>
                                    <AiFillCheckCircle />
                                </div>
                            </IconContext.Provider>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <h4 className='mx-auto'>Congratulations!</h4>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Body style={styles.modalBody}>
                        <p className="text-center">That was the correct answer.</p>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Body style={styles.modalFooter}>
                        <Button
                            className="btn btn-success btn-block"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            onClick={this.props.onSubmit}
                        >
                            OK
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal.Dialog>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

export default Feedback;
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-next",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "next": "^8.0.4-canary.21",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "npm": "^6.13.7",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-icons": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```
// next.config.js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withSass({
    cssModules: true,
    cssLoaderOptions: {
        importLoaders: 1,
        localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this outside of the Modal:

```
<Feedback
  showModal={this.state.showFeedback}
  handleHide={this.closeFeedback}
/>
```

for example, right inside the last `</>` in that file.

The reason is you are closing that modal but then are trying to trigger the Feedback modal to open, which is not possible when the first modal is hidden.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-60141594-l4lrm)

Comment: I have actually tried that but the same problem persists. When I click submit, it still clears the whole page. I have updated the original post to show what I have now

Comment: Interesting, I just ran you code and it worked. So other than that, i'm not sure. Try upgrading to Next v9 which is supported.

Comment: Ah yes, I thought so. I had a really strong feeling it had to do with my configuration. Could you tell me what your package.json and next.config.js look like? Or maybe tell me what differences there are compared to mine? I put mine in the original post for context

Comment: For this example I did not have a `next.config.js` file, as it was not needed. I then just ran this script in my package.json: `"dev": "next"` which is the default local dev environment command for next. I am using Next `v9.2.1`. I would not expect that your next.config.js has anything to do with your issue.

Comment: Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-60141594-60iv7) showing your code working with Next version `9.2.1`

Comment: (if that link doesn't work due to some issues loading the codesandbox container, this one should: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-60141594-l4lrm )

Comment: wow you're right the code does work so the problem has to do with something else besides the code. Should I just upgrade to Next 9.2.1 then? The last time I upgraded, I got a bunch of other errors and my page wouldn't even compile. That's why I'm afraid to. Could it possibly have something to do with css-loader, style-loader, and sass-loader? My problems started when I messed with that. Do I even need any of those to run my code even though I'm using scss files?

Comment: You would need to provide all of your code in order for this issue to be solved. For example, your `server/index.js` as well as any other files/components that are used for this codepath. Your `next.config.js` looks fine and the other devDependencies you mentioned aren't event used as far as I can tell from the sample of code you provided.

Comment: Here is all my code in my github repo. The most up to date code is in the debug branch. Please take a look: https://github.com/ruthvikkonda/Jeopardy/tree/debug